# Change axis label with ggpairs

Tags: r, ggally

I have created a scatter plot using ggpairs and I would like to change the axes labels to include some special characters, e.g. greek letters. Can anyone tell me how to do this?

Here is my code:

```
library(GGally)
data <- data.frame(
        "Alm"=seq(1,15,0.1), 
        "Blm"=rnorm(141,2.3,0.1),
        "siglm"=rlnorm(141,0.66,0.01),
        "sample"=c(rep("n",50),rep("p",91)
        )
ggpairs(n,columns=c("Alm","Blm","siglm"),colour="sample",diag=list(continuous='density'),axisLabels="none",upper=list(combo="facetdensity",continuous="density",params=c(alpha=0.55)),lower=list(continuous="points"))
```

I would like the axes label to look something like

```
labels=c(expression(paste(A[LM])),expression(paste(B[LM])),expression(paste(delta[L])))
```

Thanks for your help!